# MFC message pump vs Win32 message loop

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Well, I am bit confused. Things looked nice when I studied message loop in Windows programming from *Programming Windows (Charles Petzold)*. I completed initial 3 chapters (Windows messages, message loops and stuff) and thought to plunge into MFC, so now has taken up *Programming Windows with MFC (Jeff Prosise)*.

Now the question is **Is message pump in MFC is same as message loop in Win32 programming**? Or is it different concept? If different, what does that mean?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

They're roughly the same thing.

MFC's message pump implements a message loop, but introduces the [PreTranslateMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cw1sb70c.aspx) method into the mix so dialog messages can be translated by their own class instead of the main loop.

See [Meandering Through the Maze of MFC Message and Command Routing](https://web.archive.org/web/20150331003921/http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0795/dilascia/dilascia.aspx) for additional details about this feature.